# loopj jQuery Tokeninput (tokenized autocomplete) - getting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, return-value, token

Edit:  This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/45) in both accessing and removing items.  The POST functionality (to provide a set of ids) also is no longer present.

I'm using jQueryUI on my page but haven't found an adaptation of the built-in [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) function which will tokenize results Facebook-style.  There are a couple plugins built for this purpose and I'm using the [loopj](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) package to do this.

I've got it hooked up to my PHP datasource and can pull suggestions and set tokens - I'm just having a problem getting the all-up value from the input.  My understanding is that it is exposed as a list of id's (id and name being the two elements transferred to it via JSON) pertaining to the selected tokens.

Calling the following should (I think) return the value:

```
var t = $('#tokenizedinputid').val();
```

...but it comes back undefined.  Strangely, if I place this in the onAdd: parameter in initialization, it fires once upon page load and then not when tokens are added.  However this example from the demo page fires correctly, upon token addition:

```
onAdd: function (item) {
  alert("Added " + item.name);
},
```

Is there a way to adapt the above snippet to expose all of the selected tokens?  Perhaps using .each()?

Answer (score 0):

Recently added was [this patch](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/138):

var tokens = $('#tokens').tokenInput('get');

This will return all id/name pairs programatically.